# Why I can not add my project dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

When I start a new project, I see the following errors about my dependencies.
Actually, I'm using a VPN but I don't know what's the problem?!
And I didn't have this problem before, but now see that since updating my Android Studio, and I should say I searched about this problem a lot but didn't find any solution

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Open File
Show Details
```

build.gradle (Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pasargad.test_map"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

build.gradle (Project:...):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: do you connect to internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The problem was because of the proxy info in "gradle.properties" file, I deleted all of the lines about proxy (host, password, etc) and synced the project again

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have disabled the gradle offline work like the image below.[image: gradle offline work]

Now Connect Pc with the internet. Then Sync your Project Again. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that android studio is not in offline mode and re sync with internet connection and if all of those do not work then 
 
1) go to android studio folder on file explorer or something and go to gradle and then look at your gradle file (means version for example mine is **gradle-4.6-all** and then delete it) 
2)go to gradler offilce website and download the same gradle version
[gradle official site](https://gradle.org/releases/) (for example gradle v4.6)

3)unzip it and paste there where you had been deleted 
4)Re sync with internet connection